# jQuery Dynamic hide/show content of div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, hide, show

I have 4 divs with different content. Each div should change it's content depending on the link you click.

If I have 10 divs I would have to write this 10 times:

```
$( "#banner2" ).hide()
$( "#banner3" ).hide();
$( "#banner4" ).hide();

    $( "#link2" ).click(function() {
    $( "#banner1, #banner3, #banner4" ).hide()
    $( "#banner2" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {
    });
});

$( "#link1" ).click(function() {
    $( "#banner2, #banner3, #banner4" ).hide();
    $( "#banner1" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {
    });
});

$( "#link3" ).click(function() {
    $( "#banner1, #banner2, #banner4" ).hide();
    $( "#banner3" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {
    });
});

$( "#link4" ).click(function() {
    $( "#banner1, #banner2, #banner3" ).hide();
    $( "#banner4" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {
    });
});
```

Any idea of how to make it more dynamic?

Comment: `<a href="#" class="link" data-banner-target="#banner1">...</a>` <= Give all your links a common class.  Give all your banners a class of `banner`.  Then on click of a `.link`, hide all the `.banner` whose id does not equal `data('banner-target')`, and then show the one that does equal.

Comment: Can you use toggle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) for this...

Where `^=` means "starts with".

Notice that it is ok to use in JS ansd CSS.

```js
$("[id^='link']").click(function(){
  $("[id^='banner']").hide()
  let num = this.id.replace("link","")
  $("#banner"+num).fadeIn("slow")
})
```

```css
[id^='link']{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dd4ed3;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
[id^='link']:after{
  content: " | "
}
[id^='banner']{
display: none;
  padding: 2em;
  margin: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<a href="#" id="link1">Banner #1</a>
<a href="#" id="link2">Banner #2</a>
<a href="#" id="link3">Banner #3</a>
<a href="#" id="link4">Banner #4</a>
<a href="#" id="link5">Banner #5</a>
<a href="#" id="link6">Banner #6</a>
<a href="#" id="link7">Banner #7</a>
<a href="#" id="link8">Banner #8</a>
<a href="#" id="link9">Banner #9</a>
<a href="#" id="link10">Banner #10</a>
</div>

<div id="banner1">Banner #1</div>
<div id="banner2">Banner #2</div>
<div id="banner3">Banner #3</div>
<div id="banner4">Banner #4</div>
<div id="banner5">Banner #5</div>
<div id="banner6">Banner #6</div>
<div id="banner7">Banner #7</div>
<div id="banner8">Banner #8</div>
<div id="banner9">Banner #9</div>
<div id="banner10">Banner #10</div>
```

Using a common class on all links, like Taplar advised:

```js
$(".bannerLink").click(function(){
  $("[id^='banner']").hide()
  let num = this.getAttribute("data-target")
  $("#banner"+num).fadeIn("slow")
})
```

```css
.bannerLink{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dd4ed3;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.bannerLink:after{
  content: " | "
}
[id^='banner']{
display: none;
  padding: 2em;
  margin: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<a href="#" class="bannerLink" data-target="1">Banner #1</a>
<a href="#" class="bannerLink" data-target="2">Banner #2</a>
<a href="#" class="bannerLink" data-target="3">Banner #3</a>
<a href="#" class="bannerLink" data-target="4">Banner #4</a>
<a href="#" class="bannerLink" data-target="5">Banner #5</a>
<a href="#" class="bannerLink" data-target="6">Banner #6</a>
<a href="#" class="bannerLink" data-target="7">Banner #7</a>
<a href="#" class="bannerLink" data-target="8">Banner #8</a>
<a href="#" class="bannerLink" data-target="9">Banner #9</a>
<a href="#" class="bannerLink" data-target="10">Banner #10</a>
</div>

<div id="banner1">Banner #1</div>
<div id="banner2">Banner #2</div>
<div id="banner3">Banner #3</div>
<div id="banner4">Banner #4</div>
<div id="banner5">Banner #5</div>
<div id="banner6">Banner #6</div>
<div id="banner7">Banner #7</div>
<div id="banner8">Banner #8</div>
<div id="banner9">Banner #9</div>
<div id="banner10">Banner #10</div>
```

Or more flexiblility using child index retreived from [.index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/)...

```js
$(".bannerLink").click(function(){
  $(".banner").hide()
  let num = $(this).index()
  $(".banner").eq(num).fadeIn("slow")
})
```

```css
.bannerLink{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dd4ed3;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.bannerLink:after{
  content: " | "
}
.banner{
display: none;
  padding: 2em;
  margin: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<a href="#" class="bannerLink">Banner #1</a>
<a href="#" class="bannerLink">Banner #2</a>
<a href="#" class="bannerLink">Banner #3</a>
<a href="#" class="bannerLink">Banner #4</a>
<a href="#" class="bannerLink">Banner #5</a>
<a href="#" class="bannerLink">Banner #6</a>
<a href="#" class="bannerLink">Banner #7</a>
<a href="#" class="bannerLink">Banner #8</a>
<a href="#" class="bannerLink">Banner #9</a>
<a href="#" class="bannerLink">Banner #10</a>
</div>

<div class="banner">Banner #1</div>
<div class="banner">Banner #2</div>
<div class="banner">Banner #3</div>
<div class="banner">Banner #4</div>
<div class="banner">Banner #5</div>
<div class="banner">Banner #6</div>
<div class="banner">Banner #7</div>
<div class="banner">Banner #8</div>
<div class="banner">Banner #9</div>
<div class="banner">Banner #10</div>
```

In short... There is many ways you can do it... ;)